# Is there any way to have dynamic level sepearation for each node in my vis.js network?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vis.js, vis.js-network

In my vis js Network the root is very far away from the next levels (See below image).

[image]

How do I change the root position in order to have a smaller network?

I don't want to change the whole net's level separation, only the root's level separation from the next level.

Thank you

Comment: do you have physics enabled?

Comment: No, how should i use physics for it?

Comment: well, you can use various approaches. One is to use physics and adjust edges' length, another is to position all the nodes by setting their `x` and `y` (which will work with physics disabled).. anyway, I'd suggest you to show a [mcve] so that we can discuss something specific, not just theory

Comment: I would like to know how to give different node spacing value for each level actually. For example , make the nodes closer each other only for the last level

Comment: again, this depends on the options that you use already, so please post the relevant code